# panic: runtime error: index out of range [5] with length 5

Tags: for-loop, go

I wrote this program,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    x := "Hello"

    for i := 0; i <= 10; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("%#U\n", x[i])
    }
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/yrMu2hlAvkZ

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range [5] with length 5
```

I know the reason why it's giving the error, it's due to the condition in for loop `i<=10` and if I remove the `=` it will not give me the error.

But let's say I want to code it in such a way that I won't get errors if I still use `i<=10`. How can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either change your condition, from `i <= 10` to

```
i <= 4 // 4 is the last index of your string
```

or you can increase your string length, from `x := "Hello"` to

```
x := "Hello World"
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to code it in such a way that I won't get error if i still use
> "i<=10". How can it be done?

You can safely loop like this,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    x := "Hello"
    for i := 0; i <= 10 && i < len(x); i++ {
        fmt.Printf("%#U\n", x[i])
    }
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/2NknjS3Ql6k

Or this,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    x := "Hello"
    for i := 0; i <= 10; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("%#U\n", x[i%len(x)])
    }
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/0eKTcxXipwB